# File keeps downloading in a default download folder

Tags: python, selenium

I have a basic setup method:

```
class BaseTestCase(object):


    def setUp(self): 
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://qa.smartsimpleqa.com")



    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

When I am calling this setup method in another test. My file keeps downloading in a defaults download folder whereas I want to download my file after the click in the `C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject\"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Also be aware that if you set wrong path as "download.default_directory" value, you will get no exceptions- chromedriver will just use Downloads folder as default